# How to Perform a Regex Task in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

So I am trying to find a way for R to detect the characters "ar1" for a function I am making.

```
if(str_detect(as.character(y1.AR2), regex('ar1', ignore_case = T)) == T){
  print('love')
} else {
  print('nolove')
}
```

For example, the above code evaluates out to True, but I want it evaluate to false because there is no 'AR1', in the order 'A' followed by 'R' followed by '1', in the name of the object 'y1.AR2'. The only time I want the statement to evaluate to True is if it matches 'AR1' in that order whether it is in upper or lowercase.

Anyone know of a way to make this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `y1.AR2` is an object. You want to detect based on the object's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
func <- function(x) {
  xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if (grepl("ar1", xname, ignore.case = TRUE)) "love" else "nolove"
}
y1.AR2 <- 1
func(y1.AR2)
# [1] "nolove"

y1.AR1 <- 2
func(y1.AR1)
# [1] "love"
```

Finding the name of an argument to a function is a little fragile. For instance, doing

```r
func(c("1", "quux", "tar1234"))
# [1] "love"
```

because `deparse(substitute(x))` resolved to the literal expression used to form the first argument.